# Get current filename in Babel Plugin?

Tags: babeljs

I'm attempting to write a plugin for babel, and am needing the filename of the current file that is being parsed.  I know the lines of the code are passed in, but I haven't managed to find a reference to the filename.  Any help??

For instance given this code what could I do

```
export default function({ types: t }) {
  return {
    visitor: {
      Identifier(path) {
       // something here??
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can you `this` or use the 2nd parameter in a visitor (`state`)

```
Identifier(path, state) {
    console.log(state.file.opts.filename);
}
```

Comment: Why not state.filename?

Answer (score 9):

For any future viewers, you can use this.file.opts.filename in a visitor function